# Assigning multiple sql result values to the same key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a sql result of this form:

```
Id Amount1 Amount2 Amount3
1  10      10       12
2  20      13       14
3  30      15       15
```

I am trying to store the Id in Key and all other values in value

something like this:

```
{1=>{:Amount1=>"10", :Amount2=>"10", :Amount3=>"12"}, 2=>{:Amount1=>"20", :Amount2=>"13", :Amount3=>"14"}}
```

This is what I currently have so far:

```
hashn = Hash.new

  sqlresult.each { |x|  
    hashn[x['PPS_Id']] = x['Gift_Card_Amount1']
    hashn[x['PPS_Id']] = x['Gift_Card_Amount2']
    hashn[x['PPS_Id']] = x['Gift_Card_Amount3']
}
```

I believe this overrides the previous value can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an array to a hash key as well

Something like folllowing

```
hashn= {}

  sqlresult.each { |x|  
    hashn[x['PPS_Id']] = [] unless hashn[x['PPS_Id']]
    hashn[x['PPS_Id']] << x['Gift_Card_Amount1']
    hashn[x['PPS_Id']] <<  x['Gift_Card_Amount2']
    hashn[x['PPS_Id']] << x['Gift_Card_Amount3']
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Sql Result is a active record collection, this should work:

```
required_hash = {}
sqlresult.each do |obj|
  required_hash[obj.id] =
   { amount1: obj.amount1, amount2: obj.amount2, amount3: obj.amount3 }
end
required_hash
```